# Suggest a better approach on how to avoid multiple refresh token calls?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, afnetworking, alamofire

Hi I need a better solution like a good approach to be followed for the following case. 

**Scenario**

- I using some networking library like Afnetworking / Alamofire or any for network requests in mobile app.
- we are using JWT token process for authorization. And on each request's header will carry the JWT token
- There are scenarios when the token gets expired and we call refresh token API to refresh the token.

Consider in a view controller im making 3 network calls parallely during the time when JWT token has expired. 

In this scenario, whats happening is all 3 calls are requested and for each call refresh token API is called. 

How to avoid calling refresh api call 3 times and perform it only once per any number of calls in that scenario. 
But at the same time other API calls should be requested with new JWT token. 

How to achieve it?

Comment: refresh token on each `application didFinishLaunchWithOptions`, we didn't face a single problem with this

Comment: @JuicyFruit: This seems a good way, but even in this case we are requesting the JWT token without even its expired, this still asks for other possible solutions, I also thought we could request for JWT in didFinishLaunch as you said but only when the expiry time(comes with every JWT token fetch) reaches. The same time dealing with it could be problematic in cases when we signin from other devices.